# How to make an API call on props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm creating a hackernews-clone using [this API](https://hn.algolia.com/api)

This is my component structure

```
-main
   |--menubar
   |--articles
   |--searchbar
```

Below is the code block which I use to fetch the data from external API.

```
componentWillReceiveProps({search}){
    console.log(search);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchdata('story');
}

fetchdata(type = '', search_tag = ''){
    var url = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=';
    fetch(`${url}${type}&query=${search_tag}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.props.getData(data.hits);
    });
}
```

I'm making the API call in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method(as it should be) and getting the data correctly on startup. 
But here I need to pass a search value through **searchbar** component to **menubar** component to do a custom search. As I'm using only react (not using redux atm) I'm passing it as a `prop` to the **menubar** component.
As the mentioned codeblock if I search **react** and passed it through props, it logs **react** once (as I'm calling it on `componentWillReceiveProps()`). But if I run `fetchData` method inside `componentWillReceiveProps` with `search` parameter I receive it goes an infinite loop. And it goes an infinite loop even before I pass the search value as a prop.

So here, how can I call `fetchdata()` method with updating `props` ?

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000698/react-call-function-on-props-change) stackoverflow answers but making an API call in `componentWillReceiveProps` doesn't work.

So where should I call the `fetchdata()` in my case ? Is this because of asynchronous ?

**Update** : [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/o985m55kj6) for the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this by composition and handle the data fetching in the `main` HoC (higher order component).

For example:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  handleInput(event) {
    const searchValue = event.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(searchValue);
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" onChange={this.handleInput} />;
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      hits: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchdata('story');
  }

  fetchdata(type = '', search_tag = '') {
    var url = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=';
    fetch(`${url}${type}&query=${search_tag}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ hits: data.hits });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MenuBar />
        <SearchBar onChange={this.fetchdata} />
        <Articles data={this.state.hits} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Have the `fetchdata` function in the `main` component and pass it to the `SearchBar` component as a `onChange` function which will be called when the search bar input will change (or a search button get pressed).

What do you think?

Comment: Thanks. But I'm thinking of keeping `main` component clean. That's why I'm using the API call on `menubar` component. And I'm little bit new to react. So still HOC is bit confusing to me. Anyway Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by

```
componentWillReceiveProps({search}){
  if (search !== this.props.search) {
    this.fetchdata(search);
  }
}
```

but I think the right way would be to do it in `componentDidUpdate` as [react docs](//reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) say

> This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchdata('story');
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.search !== prevProps.search) {
    this.fetchdata(this.props.search);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. This works. But why you mention the second approach as the right way ?

Comment: As for me, `componentWillReceiveProps` is some kind of preparation, not a place to execute business logic. But there can be other mentions.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that inside `this.props.getData()` you change a state value, which is ultimately passed on as a prop? This would then cause the `componentWillReceiveProps` function to be re-called.
You can probably overcome this issue by checking if the `search` prop has changed in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps ({search}) {
  if (search !== this.props.search) {
    this.fetchdata(search);
  }
}
```