# React - getDerivedStateFromProps and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I would like to set state variable `books` as result of API. I cannot do it in `componentDidMount`, because I don't have token at the beginning and need it to get result from API. Nothing happens with state `books` when I run following code. If I put `state.books=res.data` before return I got a result, but after manually refresh page.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            books: [],
        };
    }
```

and

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, state) {
        if (nextProps.token){
            axios.defaults.headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Token " + nextProps.token
            }
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book/own/')
                .then(res => {
                    return {
                        books: res.data,
                    }  
                }) 
       }
```

data from the API looks like:

```
{
  id: 66,
  isbn: "9780545010221",
  title: "Title",
  author: "Author,Author",
}
```

In the render method I call component with `this.static.books` data.

Could you please advise me?

Comment: `state.books` is an array and `res.data` seems to be an object.

Comment: Don't fetch in `getDerivedStateFromProps`, use the other lifecycle hooks, like `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data when a React component prop changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000698/how-to-fetch-data-when-a-react-component-prop-changes)

Comment: use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. getDerivedStateFromProps is for advanced use cases and not for doing async shit.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common pitfall: you are returning something inside the promise handler (`then`), thinking that that would return from the function that created the promise (`getDerivedStateFromProps`). That's not the case.

I'm afraid you can't use `getDerivedStateFromProps` for asynchronous code like this. However, you don't have to, given that react is, uhm, reactive.

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.token) {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book/own/')
      .then(res => this.setState({books: res.data})) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would fetch each update since you're not validating if the value changed, just checking if it exists.